# Is there a high level command in (C#) TCP for sending a packet and blocking to wait for a reply?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have a server and client listening with a while loop to process packets sent to each other.
But there are some functions on the client that I would like to send a packet and process the reply on the same function without having to receive the command on its while loop.

Example:

```
private static string GetMyEmailFromServer() => SendAndGetPacket("GetMyEmail");
```

The example above sends a packet to the server with the string "GetMyEmail" and waits until it receives a message back then returns the value. The function "SendAndGetPacket" is using an already existing connection to the server to make the request.

As of right now, I have been creating a secondary connection to the server on another port (instead of using the already open and auth connection). I considered creating a whole framework to manage the receiving packets into different channels, where just 1 of the channels are processed in the "while loop" in the client, but I would like to know if there is a high level command for it in C#. Also, if you have a better idea than channels or a guide to implementing an effective channel system, I would appreciate a link or book (doesn't have to be language specified).

Haribol

Comment: Sounds like you should use a pre-built framework that supports messaging for you like WCF.

Comment: This is an age old problem of client/server communications, sending and receiving packets, duplex communication, async, etc. You can roll your own or you can use higher level frameworks. You will have to write a whole bunch of code to properly maintain the states. For example, remember that TCP is a streaming protocol, so when you receive something you are not guaranteed to receive the entire "GetMeMail" string in one shot. You could get "get" on first receive and "memail" on a second receive. 
I suggest you drop what you are doing and consider a framework like @ScottChamberlain said

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, however, I have done such thing in the past; I have quite much of experience on this. However, it was for a very specific reason, so I need quite some time to implement it in the new system and i needed some of the code to be working as soon as possible. Thus I wondered if there was a high level command to use it as a quick fix. Also, I was up for comparing my system with others if there were any that could be linked to me or even read a book on guidelines for such kind of network programming if there is any. (What I will changed to later is a framework over UDP)